# ActiveMQ OnMessage() method blocks other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

Iam writing an application using ActiveMQ where iam using asynchronous onMessage() method to get messages from ActiveMQ.
    Assume i get 1000 messages from activemq so all the messages will be stored in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue in OnMessage() method and i use a thread to retrieve from the ConcurrentLinkedQueue.
 But the problem iam facing is iam unable to add or retrive even a single message to or from the ConcurrentLinkedQueue and the textMessage from onMessage() is send to a setter method which takes a textMessage but iam unable get anything from getter method.Why is this?How to avoid this?

The code snippet is as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JMSException {

//Create a producer
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(queue,settext));
        producer.start();
//Create a Consumer with coresize 4 and Max size 10
        final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 10, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

        for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Consumer(queue));
        }

        **//INITIALIZE ACTIVEMQ CONFIGURATION HERE**

        consumer.setMessageListener(new QueueMessageListener());
        executor.shutdown();
    }

private static class QueueMessageListener implements MessageListener {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                //Setting the text message to a setter which takes TextMessage as arg
                settext.setTextmessage((TextMessage) message);
            }
        }
    }

 //Problem here unable to produce
class Producer implements Runnable {

    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue;
    Settext settext;
    Producer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue2, Settext settext){
        this.queue = queue2;
        this.settext=settext;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Producer Started");
        try {
            if(this.settext.getTextmessage()!=null)
            {
               //Add to ConcurrentLinkedQueue
                queue.add(this.settext.getTextmessage());
            }
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(200);
            //}
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//Problem here unable to consume
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue;

    public Consumer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue2) {
        this.queue = queue2;
    }
    public void run() {
        TextMessage str;
        System.out.println("Consumer Started");
        while ((str = queue.poll()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Removed: " + str);

        }
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont know why you do this but there is problems in your design, see notes 1- 5 below, note that the `QueueMessageListener` is executed asynchronously and it can change  `settext.setTextmessage((TextMessage) message);` before another consumer retrieve the TextMessage and add it to the queue, for this maybe V2 is better but maybe using [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html) is the best solution :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JMSException {

//Create a producer
// 1- settext.getTextmessage() == null i suppose at this level, see 2- point
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(queue,settext));
        producer.start();
//Create a Consumer with coresize 4 and Max size 10
        final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 10, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

        // 3- you start consumers go to 4, note that you will only consume count messages !!
        for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Consumer(queue));
        }

        **//INITIALIZE ACTIVEMQ CONFIGURATION HERE**

        consumer.setMessageListener(new QueueMessageListener());
        executor.shutdown();
    }

private static class QueueMessageListener implements MessageListener {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                //Setting the text message to a setter which takes TextMessage as arg
                settext.setTextmessage((TextMessage) message);
                // at this point message is considered as delivered if sessionAcknowledgeModeName is AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE and maybe lost if asynchronous treatment fails
            }
        }
    }

 //Problem here unable to produce
class Producer implements Runnable {

    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue;
    Settext settext;
    Producer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue2, Settext settext){
        this.queue = queue2;
        this.settext=settext;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Producer Started");
        try {
        // 2- settext.getTextmessage() == null if block is not executed and thread will sleep and finish
    // you have to add this         
            while (this.settext.getTextmessage() == null) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
            if(this.settext.getTextmessage()!=null)
            {
               //Add to ConcurrentLinkedQueue
                queue.add(this.settext.getTextmessage());
            }
            //}
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//Problem here unable to consume
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue;

    public Consumer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue2) {
        this.queue = queue2;
    }
    public void run() {
        TextMessage str;
        System.out.println("Consumer Started");
        // 4- queue.poll() == null at this level, while loop finished, thread will sleep and finish
    // you have to add this
        while ((str = queue.poll()) == null) {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        System.out.println("Removed: " + str);
        //}
    }
```

V2:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JMSException {

//Create a Consumer with coresize 4 and Max size 10
        final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 10, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

        for (int i = 0; i <count; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Consumer(queue));
        }

        **//INITIALIZE ACTIVEMQ CONFIGURATION HERE**

        consumer.setMessageListener(new QueueMessageListener());
        executor.shutdown();
    }

private static class QueueMessageListener implements MessageListener {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                queue.add((TextMessage) message);
            }
        }
    }

//Problem here unable to consume
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue;

    public Consumer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue2) {
        this.queue = queue2;
    }
    public void run() {
        TextMessage str;
        System.out.println("Consumer Started");
        while ((str = queue.poll()) == null) {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        System.out.println("Removed: " + str);
        //}
    }
```

V3:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JMSException {

//Create a Consumer with coresize 4 and Max size 10
        final ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 10, 100, TimeUnit.SECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);

        **//INITIALIZE ACTIVEMQ CONFIGURATION HERE**

        consumer.setMessageListener(new QueueMessageListener());
        executor.shutdown();
    }

private static class QueueMessageListener implements MessageListener {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                executor.execute(new Consumer((TextMessage) message));
            }
        }
    }

//Problem here unable to consume
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    TextMessage textMessage;

    public Consumer(TextMessage textMessage) {
        this.textMessage = textMessage;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Removed: " + str);
    }
}
```

V4:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JMSException {

    new Consumer(queue).start();

    **//INITIALIZE ACTIVEMQ CONFIGURATION HERE**

    consumer.setMessageListener(new QueueMessageListener());
    executor.shutdown();
}

private static class QueueMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        queue.add((TextMessage) message);
    }
}

//Problem here unable to consume
class Consumer implements Runnable {
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue;

    public Consumer(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<TextMessage> queue2) {
        this.queue = queue2;
    }
    public void run() {
        TextMessage str;
        System.out.println("Consumer Started");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            while ((str = queue.poll()) == null) {
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Removed: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Iam sending 100 messages from ActiveMQ producer.I tried the V2 of the code but i System.out.println("Removed: " + str); prints only 10 times i.e. its removing only 10 elements from queue.Correct me if iam wrong

Comment: in this case this means that your variable count == 10 ?

Comment: maybe V3 is more flexible

Comment: Yes correct i guess thats the wrong stuff iam doing.Now with 1 consumer how to get all the messages in consume() method which are added to queue in onMessage() at any time.

Comment: No i have to use a queue as per my design

Comment: i have added V4 but with infinite loop because you need a long term condition maybe gave by ACTIVEMQ consumer to stop the Consumer thread